# Is there any way to reset sum cumulative / running total every month in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to calculate a month-to-date profit with the current date 15th, so it will sum the profit every month until the 15th day. Is there any way/idea to reset the sum cumulative / running total every month in bigquery? i want to filter the windows function so that every 1st day in the month will reset the sum cumulative in the profit_cumulative column.

so I want the result to be like this :

| Date | Categories | Profit | Profit_Cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-14 | A | 295.62 | 6350.58 |
| 2022-06-15 | A | 459.80 | 6810.38 |
| 2022-07-01 | A | 501.03 | 501.03 |
| 2022-07-02 | A | 258.97 | 760.0 |

instead of this:

| Date | Categories | Profit | Profit_Cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-14 | A | 295.62 | 6350.58 |
| 2022-06-15 | A | 459.80 | 6810.38 |
| 2022-07-01 | A | 501.03 | 7311.72 |
| 2022-07-02 | A | 258.97 | 7570.69 |

and this is my code :

````
  b AS (
  WITH
    a AS (
    SELECT
      DATE_TRUNC(DATE(created_at),day) AS date_,
      EXTRACT(YEAR
      FROM
        created_at) AS year,
      EXTRACT(MONTH
      FROM
        created_at) AS month,
      EXTRACT(DAY
      FROM
        created_at) AS day,
      SAFE_SUBTRACT(retail_price, cost) AS profit,
      products.category AS product_category
    FROM
      `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.order_items` orderitems
    INNER JOIN
      `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.products` products
    ON
      orderitems.product_id = products.id
      AND created_at >= '2022-06-01 00:00:00 UTC'
      AND created_at <='2022-08-15 23:59:59 UTC'
    GROUP BY
      date_,
      year,
      month,
      day,
      product_category,
      profit )
  SELECT
    a.date_ AS Date,
    a.year,
    a.month,
    a.day,
    a.product_category AS Product_Categories,
    SUM(a.profit) AS Profit
  FROM
    a
  WHERE
    a.day <= 15
  GROUP BY
    a.date_,
    a.year,
    a.month,
    a.day,
    a.product_category
  ORDER BY
    a.date_,
    year,
    month,
    day,
    a.product_category)
SELECT
  Date,
  b.year,
  b.month,
  b.day,
  b.Product_Categories,
  b.profit,
  SUM(Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY product_categories ORDER BY date) AS profit_cumulative
FROM
  b```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are nearly there!
You just need to add the month to your WINDOW PARTITION like so:

```
SUM(Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY product_categories, month ORDER BY date) AS profit_cumulative
```

Comment: you know what @Felix, I feel really stupid , I think I don't fully understand how partition by in window function work, and I am still learning. thanks a lot for the help Felix, it works perfectly!

Comment: No worries, you gotta start somewhere! "Partition by" kind of works just as a "Group by," therefore only values of that particular product and month combination are used for the window.
This tutorial explains the differences nicely:
https://count.co/sql-resources/bigquery-standard-sql/window-functions-explained

Comment: thanks I appreciate your support!  ah I see, that "'Partition by' kind of works just as a 'Group by'", statement makes me catch on fairly quickly, thanks for the reference link too @Felix

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to solve it with this one line of code:

```
SUM(Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY month, product_categories ORDER BY date) AS profit_cumulative
```

add the 'month' in your partition by before product categories, so it will reset the cumulative sum every 1st day of the month.

Comment: hey @rama, thank you for the answer, any ideas to easily understand how the partition works? by the way, the answer matches my needs!